# client denied by server configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I using Wamp sesrver, i got the following error, how do I fix this problem?

[client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: D:/httpd-2.2-x64, referer: http://localhost/sabredav/

my D:/  doesn't have a folder name "httpd-2.2-x64"

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in your wamp's httpd.conf file you will probably find a `<Directory D:/httpd-2.2-x64>` (or similar) configuration block. This block will probably have something like

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
```

within it. You can change the `deny from all` to `allow from all` to get rid of that error message. You should probably spend some time looking at the [Apache core](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html) configuration documentation too.

Comment: there is no <Directory D:/httpd-2.2-x64> (or similar) in my wamp's httpd.conf file so I did add it by myself <Directory D:/httpd-2.2-x64> Order allow,deny Allow from all </Directory> and I still got that error