# Django on Apache gives 500 error, error log has "client denied by server configuration"

Tags: apache2, django, 500-error

There's many questions about similar issues, but none in particular about the combination of the error 500 with Django. E.g. similar questions:

- [client denied by server configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/255335/client-denied-by-server-configuration)
- [Why does my migrated apache2-fastcgi-django solution give me 'AH01630: client denied by server configuration'?](https://serverfault.com/questions/874177/why-does-my-migrated-apache2-fastcgi-django-solution-give-me-ah01630-client-de)
- [Getting client denied when accessing a wsgi graphite script](https://serverfault.com/questions/456041/getting-client-denied-when-accessing-a-wsgi-graphite-script)

Apache error log:

```
[Wed Jun 19 18:41:44.364270 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 9386:tid 140669708334848] [client 1.2.3.4:1948] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/user/website/wsgi.py, referer: https://website.org/admin/login/?next=/admin/
```

The error is shown as:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

But this only appears when trying to access admin panel, not when browsing the pages, or downloading files behind Apache protected directories. All the Q/A's I could find talk about an error in the Apache settings, but it doesn't seem to be there (nothing was changed with Apache since install).

Answer (score 0):

The error messages were misleading. The actual cause of the bug was that the server database was being served by `sqlite`, and the file had gotten the wrong ownership during an update. It was now owned by `root` and wasn't writable by the Django Apache user (`www-data`):

```
username@servername:~/project$ ls -lsa
total 924
  4 drwxr-xrwx 7 www-data www-data    4096 Mar 22 02:48 .
  4 drwxr-xrwx 4 www-data www-data    4096 Dec 24  2017 ..
880 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     1046528 Mar 22 02:48 db.sqlite3
  4 drwxr-xrwx 5 www-data www-data    4096 Mar  2 12:56 files
  4 drwxr-xrwx 7 www-data www-data    4096 Mar 26 22:13 front
  4 drwxr-xrwx 8 www-data www-data    4096 Jun 11 15:24 .git
  4 -rwxrwxr-x 1 username username    1218 Nov  8  2018 .gitignore
  4 -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data     800 Apr  3  2017 manage.py
  4 drwxr-xrwx 3 www-data www-data    4096 Mar 26 15:42 project
  4 -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data      56 Jun  2  2017 README.md
  4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 username username      49 Nov  8  2018 requirements.txt
  4 drwxrwxrwx 4 www-data www-data    4096 Jan 11  2017 static
```

The Django admin panel updates the database upon user login into the admin panel (for record keeping), the failure to be able to do this results in a 500 error.

To fix this, just change the ownership back to normal:

```
sudo chown www-data: db.sqlite3
```